# Insert filename as column, separated by a comma

Tags: linux, bash

I have 100 file that looks like this

```
>file.csv
gene1,55
gene2,23
gene3,33
```

I want to insert the filename and make it look like this:

```
file.csv
gene1,55,file.csv
gene2,23,file.csv
gene3,33,file.csv
```

Now, I can almost get there using awk

`awk '{print $0,FILENAME}' *.csv > concatenated_files.csv`

But this prints the filenames with a space, instead of a comma. Is there a way to replace the space with a comma?

Comment: Well, how good with `sed` are you?

Comment: pretty mediocre. Is there a way to do this with awk?

Comment: Sure, I just mean `bash` alone probably won't get you there. It's worth noting this is why Perl exists, though if you can depend on Python, Ruby, or whatever, I'd steer towards that instead for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to replace the space with a comma?

Yes, change the [OFS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html)

```
$ awk -v OFS="," '{print $0,FILENAME}' file.csv
gene1,55,file.csv
gene2,23,file.csv
gene3,33,file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, turns out:

`for d in *.csv; do (awk '{print FILENAME (NF?",":"") $0}' "$d" > ${d}.all_files.csv); done`

Works just fine.

Comment: The parentheses are useless. there is no reason to run Awk in a subshell.

Comment: this doesn't print `file.csv` on the first line (as displayed in expected output); this prints the filename at the beginning of each data line but in the expected output the filename is at the end of the data tlines

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new field

```
awk -vOFS=, '{$++NF=FILENAME}1' file.csv
gene1,55,file.csv
gene2,23,file.csv
gene3,33,file.csv
```